# VBA ExportAsFixedFormat error "expected identifer"

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, export-to-pdf

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _

  Type:=xlTypePDF, ' error here expected identifer on ":="
```

On excel professional 2016 I am getting expression errors on the colon equals sign in the above code....anyone any ideas? It's been a while since I used VBA but the underscore has no characters after it and the code seems identical to the microsoft example.

Comment: It might be the line feed between the two lines of code... Continuation underscore will search for completing code in the immediately following line, and fail fast if it is empty.

Comment: That's it... I won't swear, thanks!